# How can I output bit pattern of infinity and NaN in C++?(IEEE standard)

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee

I'm reading *Computer Systems: A Programmer’s Perspective*, then I found the `Special Values`'s definition and corresponding bit patterns.

[image: bit pattern of Infinity and NaN]

Now, I wanna output their bits using C++. I use their macro to output bits, obviously is incorrect, because macro defined to Integer!

```
#define FP_NAN      0x0100
#define FP_NORMAL   0x0400
#define FP_INFINITE (FP_NAN | FP_NORMAL)
```

What should I do to correctly output bits in the image above? and, Why compiler defined those Integer macros rather than IEEE standard?

below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

union U {
    float f;
    int i;
};

int main() {

    U u1, u2;

    u1.f = FP_NAN;
    u2.f = FP_INFINITE;

    cout << bitset<32>(u1.i) << endl;
    cout << bitset<32>(u2.i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
01000011100000000000000000000000
01000100101000000000000000000000
```

My computer environment:

- win10
- mingw64

Comment: What compiler are you using and what header file did you obtain those values from? What else did the book/article say about those bit patterns? Did it mention the date type? Architecture?

Comment: Can you share your output?

Comment: Sorry, I already update question!

Comment: Did you actually check what those macro value means or did you just assume that?

Comment: Also: it is UB to access union fields like that.

Comment: @luker Just a storage form of floating-point numbers.

Comment: These macros define possible outputs of `std::fpclassify` they don't (have to) correspond to actual bitpatterns of floating point numbers.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for reminding me, The problem is that I can't correct ouput the "real" bitpatterns......or can check the low level bitpatterns?

Comment: Replace `u1.f = FP_NAN;` with `u1.f = std::nanf("");`.  Replace `u2.f = FP_INFINITE;` with `u2.f = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();`.  Writing to one union member and reading from another union member is undefined behavior in C++; use `std::memcpy` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a quick-and-dirty `double` bit-wise output program a while back.  You could modify it to work for `float`.

It has ANSI escape sequences in it, which might not be suitable for your environment.

The key part is just using a byte memory pointer and examining the bit state directly, rather than trying to get `std::bitset` to play nice.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::fpclassify;
using std::memcpy;
using std::nan;
using std::numeric_limits;
using std::reverse;
using std::setw;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::uint32_t;
using std::uint64_t;

namespace {

uint32_t low32_from(double d) {
    char const* p = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&d);
    uint32_t result;
    memcpy(&result, p, sizeof result);
    return result;
}

uint32_t high32_from(double d) {
    char const* p = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&d);
    p += 4;
    uint32_t result;
    memcpy(&result, p, sizeof result);
    return result;
}

string hexstr(uint32_t value) {
    char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    unsigned char buffer[4];
    memcpy(buffer, &value, sizeof buffer);
    auto p = &buffer[0];
    stringstream ss;
    char const* sep = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buffer; ++i) {
        ss << sep << hex[(*p >> 4) & 0xF] << hex[*p & 0xF];
        sep = " ";
        ++p;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

string bits(uint64_t v, size_t len) {
    string s;
    int group = 0;
    while (len--) {
        if (group == 4) { s.push_back('\''); group = 0; }
        s.push_back(v & 1 ? '1' : '0');
        v >>= 1;
        ++group;
    }
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}

string doublebits(double d) {
    auto dx = fpclassify(d);
    unsigned char buffer[8];
    memcpy(buffer, &d, sizeof buffer);
    stringstream ss;
    uint64_t s = (buffer[7] >> 7) & 0x1;
    uint64_t e = ((buffer[7] & 0x7FU) << 4) | ((buffer[6] >> 4) & 0xFU);
    uint64_t f = buffer[6] & 0xFU;
    f = (f << 8) + (buffer[5] & 0xFFU);
    f = (f << 8) + (buffer[4] & 0xFFU);
    f = (f << 8) + (buffer[3] & 0xFFU);
    f = (f << 8) + (buffer[2] & 0xFFU);
    f = (f << 8) + (buffer[1] & 0xFFU);
    f = (f << 8) + (buffer[0] & 0xFFU);

    ss << "sign:\033[0;32m" << bits(s, 1) << "\033[0m ";
    if (s) ss << "(-) ";
    else ss << "(+) ";

    ss << "exp:\033[0;33m" << bits(e, 11) << "\033[0m ";
    ss << "(" << setw(5) << (static_cast<int>(e) - 1023) << ") ";


    ss << "frac:";

    // 'i' for implied 1 bit, '.' for not applicable (so things align correctly).
    if (dx == FP_NORMAL) ss << "\033[0;34mi";
    else ss << "\033[0;37m.\033[34m";

    ss << bits(f, 52) << "\033[0m";

    if (dx == FP_INFINITE) ss << " \033[35mInfinite\033[0m";
    else if (dx == FP_NAN) ss << " \033[35mNot-A-Number\033[0m";
    else if (dx == FP_NORMAL) ss << " \033[35mNormal\033[0m";
    else if (dx == FP_SUBNORMAL) ss << " \033[35mDenormalized\033[0m";
    else if (dx == FP_ZERO) ss << " \033[35mZero\033[0m";

    ss << " " << d;

    return ss.str();
}

} // anon

int main() {
    auto lo = low32_from(1111.2222);
    auto hi = high32_from(1111.2222);
    cout << hexstr(lo) << "\n";
    cout << hexstr(hi) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(1111.2222) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(1.0) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(-1.0) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(+0.0) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(-0.0) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(-numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) << "\n";
    cout << doublebits(nan("")) << "\n";

    double x = 1.0;
    while (x > 0.0) {
        cout << doublebits(x) << "\n";
        x = x / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

#### Problem #1:

FP_NAN and FP_INFINITE are not constants representing return values of [`std::fpclassify`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify), which returns classification of given floating point number.

#### Problem 2:

Accessing inactive union member, i.e. not the latest assigned to, is UB. Most robust, well-known way to inspect memory representation of an object is to `memcpy` it into char buffer.

Taking it into account, you can write your code in following way:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath> // nanf
#include <cstring> // memcpy
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <ranges>



template <typename T> // Template, because reusability
void print_bits(const T& t)
{
    char buffer[sizeof(T)];
    std::memcpy(buffer, &t, sizeof(T));
    for (char c: buffer | std::views::reverse) //Endianness
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(c);
    }
}


int main()
{
    const double nan = std::nanf("");
    const double inf = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    print_bits(nan);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_bits(inf);
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

> 0111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d6c30067c9e7e6a