# How to get the padding position of a long double value in C++?

Tags: c++

The number of bits for the mantissa, exponent and sign of a `long double` value can be detected in the following way (supposing iec559):

```
template <typename T>
constexpr uint32_t bitsInExponent() 
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559);
    return std::ceil(std::log2(std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent-std::numeric_limits<T>::min_exponent+1));
}
// outputs 15 for long double on my machine/compiler

template <typename T>
constexpr uint32_t bitsInMantissa() 
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559);
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::radix == 2);
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::digits-1;
}
// outputs 63 for long double on my machine/compiler

template <typename T>
constexpr uint32_t bitsInSign() 
{
    return 1;
}
```

Consequently, the total number of bits for the `long double` is (on my machine and compiler) 79 (63+15+1), probably a IEEE-754 binary64 extended format.

However, the memory footprint of the `long double` (`sizeof(long double)`) is 16, thus 128 bits.

The padding of the float value (those 128-79, 49bits) seems to be at the higher bits on my machine with my compiler, and mostly filled with garbage.

My question is: **Are those 1-63 bits always at the higher bits of the 128 bits?**

In case the padding of the extended IEEE-754 binary-64 format is not guaranteed to be at the highest bits, **how to detect where is the padding?**

Try it:
https://onlinegdb.com/doL6E7WYL

Comment: I wrote a bit dump of `double`.  Could be adapted for `long double`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71979978/4641116

Comment: We know x86 has 80bit long doubles. So which function is wrong? The exponent or the mantissa?

Comment: It seems there is an "integer part" between the mantissa and the exponent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authoritative answer can only come from reading the ABI for your implementation.

However, if your `long double` is [80-bit extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format), then you are almost certainly on x86, since AFAIK it's the only major architecture with hardware support for that format.  In that case, unless you have a very unusual compiler with a very unusual ABI, the data is going to be in the low 10 bytes, with the padding in the high 6 bytes.  The x87 load and store instructions don't account for the padding, which is a more recent innovation to provide better alignment, so they will expect a pointer to the 10-byte data itself.  By putting the data at the low end of the 16 bytes, a `long double *` is a pointer to the data, and can be used directly with an x87 load or store.  If it were anywhere else, every memory access to a `long double` would require adding the appropriate offset, which would be inefficient.

Non-x86 platforms usually implement `long double` in one of two ways:

- Either it is just an alias for `double` (the C++ standard allows this), in which case it would normally be binary64 double precision with no padding, and `sizeof(long double) == 8`.  [MSVC++ on x86-64 does this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120710/why-did-microsoft-abandon-long-double-data-type), and doesn't give you access to the hardware's 80-bit extended precision support.
- Or, it is binary128 quadruple precision, in which case you have `sizeof(long double) == 16` and again no padding.